# How do I set a specific thickness of an Extrude Mesh in Geometry Nodes (as opposed to a Factor)?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to Extrude a Curve after the Fill Curve node.  But the scale is a factor and I want to make sure the object is an exact thickness (say 3 inches).  How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: I am not completely sure about it, but I think those values are metric. So, you can convert 3inches to meters/centimeters and put that value in there. Much easier; you can just use math nodes for that.

Comment: I wish it was a metric value, but it is acting like a factor.  I'm guessing the Offset node is where I need to look but I still don't fully comprehend the language of geonodes yet so I don't know what to plug into it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TheKalaakaar, you got me thinking which led me to figuring out a solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out and I'm leaving this here just in case anyone else needs help with this.

Just plug a Vector node into the Offset and then set your value accordingly:

[image]

Also note that it is metric, even if your scene is set to imperial, so you'd have to convert to imperial units to metric yourself or with a math node, if are working with inches or feet.  (I still can't comprehend why GeoNodes doesn't respect scene units.)